# Is it possible or necessary to close files opened by another program in a previous boot?

Tags: windows, file-io

I have the following situation in my hands.

I was playing a game made by a third party when suddenly my computer crashes. The game was in the middle of a save and the file became corrupt. I tried uninstalling then reinstalling but apparently Steam says a content file is locked.

One situation I thought of was the possibility of the game (it's an independent title using Unreal Engine so I didn't expect much) being in the middle of a write, marking a file as open, and therefore the file itself needs to be closed so that Steam could open and overwrite it upon reinstall.

So that's what I'm trying to do right now - write a program that closes any file and therefore allow it to be opened again.

Once I could do that, the next step is iterating over multiple files in a folder, which could/should be answered elsewhere in SO.

And yes, I restarted multiple times and the behavior remains consistent.

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing in SO that asks this question. On the other hand, for some reason my game works again so I don't actually need to write this program, but having this question might be useful for new programmers like myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tool like the "[Microsoft Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)" if you just want to close it.

If you want to write a program to do it, take a look at the [System.Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8) namespace in C#.